# How is Google Chrome managing authentication to sites?

Tags: authentication, chrome

In Chrome, every tab is its own process. Yet, logging in to a site, say, Facebook, persists across tabs. For that matter, in many cases, it persists across OS reboots. This seems inherently very very insecure, but I'm just wondering, how is Chrome implementing this? The reboot thing in particular means it is storing something like a session token even after the process is terminated, which allows seamlessly reconnecting, already authenticated, with secure sites.

Comment: Good questions; however I would recommend that you split the last question into a separate one, since it is a separate, more generalized question.

Comment: I'll move the second part to its own question.

Comment: This isn't specific to Chrome. All browsers do this.

Comment: 1. Why do you think it is "inherently very very secure"?  What threats/risks are you worried about?  What is your threat model?  I suspect you are making judgements that might not have a strong basis in the actual risks, or that aren't a significant issue for most users.  2. The last paragraph about Mozilla/Firefox is probably off-topic on this site (too broad, too dependent on opinion) and in any case does not belong in this question.

Comment: *in*secure (you misquoted). I am specifically worried about ongoing data being taken from my laptop (and for that matter, other devices), including keylogging, or more active snooping on arbitrary file contents. Assume I'm at greater risk than most users, and know that I can't say more about why that is the case. Therefore I'm seeking technical knowledge to help me sanitize as much as possible my laptop, so that I might have privacy. It may be this ultimately requires replacing the machine.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**With a cookie!**

Chrome, like any other browser, is storing a cookie in your file system. Those cookies are what enable you to reconnect automatically to some site. Since it's in your file system, even if you reboot they will still be there. Multiple processes or not is irrelevant here.

Then you might wonder, if the cookies are in my file system, does it mean that any page can access them?

**No**. Only the page for which the cookie was created can access it. The one that enforces this policy is your browser. If your browser is doing its job correctly then you are ok since it will only send the cookie to the right site (server).

You can also access the cookies directly by looking at the file system, but for that you need to have access to the operating system. Webpages don't have access to that hence the browser is doing that job for them and only gives them the cookies they should be able to read.

**Fun thing**

You need to protect your cookies. Stealing your cookies is nearly the same as stealing your password/username. If someone or something, like a virus, steals the cookies residing on your computer, it can impersonate you on that website if you are currently logged in.

You can check, edit and add cookie with tool like firebug. So, if you want to mount a fake attack you can :

- log in on a website using chrome
- read the cookie in chrome using the developer tool
- open firefox with firebug and add the authentication cookie that you found in chrome

You will then be logged into that website in firefox as well as in chrome. This is a simplistic version of the hack session hijacking. You could transfer the cookie onto another computer if you want to.

Comment: Often, the server autologin is unique to a browser instance as well; the server sends a session token (completely unrelated to credentials) which it associates with the header information and source IP provided by the browser the user is logging in from. So, if that same token is provided from a FF browser when the user logged in with Chrome, or if the token's provided by a computer with a different source IP than the one used to process the login, the server refuses the request and invalidates the token. There are workarounds, but it's usually not so simple as copying a cookie.

Comment: This is all good info, thanks. Couple other questions: how does rottentomatoes.com know which of my FB friends have "Liked" certain movies, based on the fact that I happen to be authenticated with facebook.com? This would seem to require a page at domain B to read the cookie from domain A, no?

Comment: @JasonBoyd off the top of my head, rottentomatoes.com might load a widget from Facebook in an iframe or something. Like `<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/widget/friends-who-like/id-of-movie">`. When your browser requests to load this URL, it sends cookies associated with `.facebook.com` to the Facebook server, which returns a small HTML page with some of your friends' photos. Rotten Tomatoes doesn't see your Facebook session ID, at least not from the HTTP request. Of course that's just a simple example of how it might be done.

Comment: In the last example, rottentomatoes not only not see facefook session id, but even the list being displayed as a part of their page.

Comment: Hi! You could add something about third-party cookies, since "no other site can access this information" is probably not entirely correct. Since many pages with e.g. facebook integration can indirectly access your information via the integration, if you allow third-party-cookies

Comment: Cookie stealing is one of the reasons that, often to make any important decisions, requires you to re-enter your password.

Answer (score 10):

From this page: http://blog.chromium.org/2008/09/multi-process-architecture.html

> There's only one browser process, which manages the tabs, windows, and "chrome" of the browser.  This process also handles all interactions with the disk, network, user input, and display, but it makes no attempt to parse or render any content from the web.

And from the section about Renderer tabs:

> Each renderer process is run in a sandbox, which means it has almost no direct access to your disk, network, or display.  All interactions with web apps, including user input events and screen painting, must go through the browser process.  This lets the browser process monitor the renderers for suspicious activity, killing them if it suspects an exploit has occurred.

I'm assuming the "interactions with the disk, network, user input" part includes session cookies and such like.

Comment: I have deleted my answer earlier about threads and am trying to work a better one, but sites of the same domain use the same process (I would venture to guess threading) "We also have strategies to assign new tabs to existing processes if the total number of processes is too large, or if the user already has a process open navigated to that domain." - http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture

Comment: Shared threads per domain makes sense. Thanks that's a useful bit to know.

Answer (score 4):

First, in specific to Google Chrome you will find [This article](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/threading) very useful.  CullenJ mentioned before that Chrome uses processes not threads, but that is untrue.  It uses both.  According to the article linked above Chrome uses a thread to handle SQlite database operations and gives the example of cookie operations so we can assume that Chrome stores cookies in a SQLite database somewhere.

Now let's take a look at the following quote:

> We discourage locking and threadsafe objects. Instead, objects live on only one thread, we pass messages between threads for communication, and we use callback interfaces (implemented by message passing) for most cross-thread requests.

So, we know that google uses message passing and we can find more information on it reading about [IPC](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/inter-process-communication).

Which states:

> Chromium has a multi-process architecture which means that we have a lot of processes communicating with each other. Our main inter-process communication primitive is the named pipe. On Linux & OS X, we use a socketpair(). A named pipe is allocated for each renderer process for communication with the browser process. The pipes are used in asynchronous mode to ensure that neither end is blocked waiting for the other.
>
> Within the browser, communication with the renderers is done in a separate I/O thread. Messages to and from the views then have to be proxied over to the main thread using a ChannelProxy. The advantage of this scheme is that resource requests (for web pages, etc.), which are the most common and performance critical messages, can be handled entirely on the I/O thread and not block the user interface. These are done through the use of a ChannelProxy::MessageFilter which is inserted into the channel by the RenderProcessHost. This filter runs in the I/O thread, intercepts resource request messages, and forwards them directly to the resource dispatcher host. See Multi-process Resource Loading for more information on resource loading.
>
> Each renderer also has a thread that manages communication (in this case, the main thread), with the rendering and most processing happening on another thread (see the diagram in multi-process architecture). Most messages are sent from the browser to the WebKit thread through the main renderer thread and vice-versa. This extra thread is to support synchronous renderer-to-browser messages (see "Synchronous messages" below).

If you were wondering what a named pipe is [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) gives this definition:

> A named pipe is system-persistent and exists beyond the life of the process and can be deleted once it is no longer being used. Processes generally attach to the named pipes (usually appearing as a file) to perform inter-process communication.

Now, I would to get one last quote from the [documentation dealing with multi process architecture](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture).  It reads as follows:

> We also have strategies to assign new tabs to existing processes if the total number of processes is too large, or if the user already has a process open navigated to that domain.

I also read in one of their documents that they consider subdomains to be the same domain as the root domain for JavaScript compatibility.  For example: sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com and example.com are considered to be the same domain by Chrome.

So this may not be how chrome does it exactly (but, you can read further into it following their documentation) but, based on what I've read so far I could implement a browser doing the following:

1. I browse to facebook.com and the browser starts a new renderer and creates a named pipe
2. I login and the renderer sends a message to the database thread to store the cookie
3. I open some more unrelated sites and browser creates more renderers and pipes
4. For some reason I feel like opening another tab to facebook.com browser and the browser messages the renderer that has already opened facebook.com to render another tab too.
5. The new tab has all information available to the first facebook.com tab because they are sharing a process (I would have the process store its own copy of a cookie or something for reading so I would not have to bother the database thread, but that may not be how Chrome does it).
6. If I decide to sign out the database thread sees that the cookie has changed and writes it to the database.  If I stay signed in it does not touch the database.

Now, I must add here that default cookie lifetime is when the browser closes it expires.  So, to support across opening and closing the browser the website must tell it to override this lifetime (which many sites do).

Ok, so if a browser overrides its cookies lifetime then it is stored in the database (yes, on the file system) and will be read again when you go back to this site.  Is it insecure to store it there? No, not if your computer is not compromised and that the OS is doing its job properly.

As a side note, operating systems have come along way in detecting and blocking attacks.

As far as going to another browser, they all do similar things for cookie storage and if it bothers you that much either use Chrome's Incognito mode or see this [documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en) which states:

> If you want Google Chrome to automatically delete cookies when you close all your browser windows, select the "Keep local data only until I quit my browser" checkbox in the Content Settings dialog. You can also make exceptions so that specific sites’ cookies are deleted whenever you close your browser.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but rootkit malware can read any file on the hard drive, no? I mean, can bypass root access, which is at the OS level. This would include cookies that can authenticate to things like Facebook, and if these could be sent over encrypted SSL traffic to wherever, doesn't this mean a rootkit *could* gain access to things like web based mail, social media accounts, etc. without being detected at all by common AV tools?

Comment: You are correct, a computer with a root kit would be considered a compromised computer.  I believe most AV programs try to deal with them by preventing their initial install if I am not mistaken.  If you suspect your system has one the best option would be to reinstall the OS (on sure way) 2nd best would probably to use an alternative trusted medium.  Could be as simple as a Linux Live CD with ClamAV.